# Getting Wrong Answer on CSES Problem Set Hotel Queries

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1143/

I am trying to solve this problem, I used Segment Tree for solving it. I tried every possible test cases but it is not getting accepted.

Just failing in one test case which is too big. Please help me out to solve this problem ..!!!

[Solution : https://cses.fi/paste/072a5f07ec4a533b18c669/](https://cses.fi/paste/072a5f07ec4a533b18c669/)

[image: Test results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is when a group of guests don't fit. Your code will recurse down the right spine, then go past because the test `l == r && seg[index] >= val` will be false. The result is that you treat the leaf corresponding to the last hotel as a branch and zero it out as the max of the two empty children whose `seg` values are uninitialized.

If I'm right, then this test should fail:

```
1 2
1
2 1
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked..!!

if(x > seg[0])
{
    cout<<"0 ";
    continue;
}

I added this condition and it worked..!!